# Radial (or Circular) Bar Chart in r highcharter package doesn't work as I want

Tags: r, highcharts

I want to obtain a chart like the one in the link below. The problem is that in r with highcharter package and the polar=TRUE,  the bars starts in the origin, and I don't whant that. I will let you the code below and I wish someone can help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-polar/column-inverted-inner

```
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(type = "column", inverted=TRUE, polar =TRUE, marginTop=40) %>%
hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal", borderWidth=0,
                         pointPadding=0, groupPadding=0.15)) %>%
hc_add_series(data=c(29, 106, 144, 135, 216, 95),
          name="Data") %>%
hc_xAxis(type= 'categories', lineWith=0) %>%
hc_yAxis(min=0, max=250, lineWith=0, showLastLabel=TRUE) %>%
hc_pane(size= '80%', innerSize='15%', startAngle=0, endAngle=270)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharter uses Highcharts version 7.2.0:

[image]

But features in the demo above (radial chart and pane's innerSize) were added to Highcharts in 8.0.0 and 8.0.1, see the changelog:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v8.0.0
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v8.0.1

You need to wait for the Highcharter wrapper update. You can contact the Highcharter's author here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues

Comment: I really appreciate your fast answer, and you're right, its a version issue, I already posted my question in the github page you sent to me. I wish we could have an updated highchart package for r ASAP.

Comment: If you believe that the answer is correct, please mark it properly :)